# Angular "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to implement [ng2-image-viewer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-image-viewer) to my project. SO far everything is working smoothly by when i am trying to pass URL of the image to this plugin, console is throwing strange error yet everything is working smoothly.

Following is my

**showcase.component.html**,

```
<p>{{ activatedRouteArt | json }}</p>
<div id="image-viewer-container">
    <app-image-viewer 
    [images]="[artURL]"
    [loadOnInit]="true"
    [idContainer]="'idOnHTML'"
    [showOptions]="true"
    >
    </app-image-viewer>
</div>
```

**showcase.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { RawImportData } from 'src/app/models/common/raw-import-data';
import { Artdata } from 'src/app/models/artdata';
import { DataService } from 'src/app/services/data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-showcase',
  templateUrl: './showcase.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./showcase.component.scss']
})
export class ShowcaseComponent implements OnInit {

  activatedRouteArt: RawImportData<Artdata> = new RawImportData();
  activatedRouteID: number;
  artURL:string;

  constructor(private dataService: DataService,private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.activatedRouteID = +params.id;
    });
    this.fetchArts('all',this.activatedRouteID,'1','50');
  }
  fetchArts(route:string ='all', id:any, page:any, limit:any){
    this.dataService.getArtsAPI(route, id.toString(), page.toString(), limit.toString()).subscribe((data: RawImportData<Artdata>)=>{
      if(data) this.activatedRouteArt=data;
      this.artURL=this.dataService.dataServerURL+this.activatedRouteArt.records['0'].URL;
      console.log(this.artURL);
    }); 
  }
}
```

This is the error console is throwing, but it's not doing anything, i mean, my image is displayed already.

[image]

```
Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
ImageViewerComponent.html:1 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined
    at ImageViewerComponent.push../node_modules/ng2-image-viewer/ng2-image-viewer.umd.js.ImageViewerComponent.isURlImagem (ng2-image-viewer.umd.js:315)
    at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (ImageViewerComponent.html:1)
    at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (core.js:45293)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:44276)
    at callViewAction (core.js:44636)
    at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:44593)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:44271)
    at callViewAction (core.js:44636)
    at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:44593)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:44271)
View_ImageViewerComponent_17 @ ImageViewerComponent.html:1
...
showcase.component.ts:30 http://localhost/artworks/art/a/abbati/abbati1.jpg
client:52 [WDS] Live Reloading enabled.
```

### EDIT

When i replace the URL with staic string, error goes away, eg. No error in this case

**showcase.component.html**

```
<p>{{ activatedRouteArt | json }}</p>
<div id="image-viewer-container">
    <app-image-viewer 
    [images]="['http://localhost/artworks/art/a/abbati/abbati1.jpg']"
    [loadOnInit]="true"
    [idContainer]="'idOnHTML'"
    [showOptions]="true"
    >
    </app-image-viewer>
</div>
```

Comment: Try to put ```*ngIf="artURL"``` in ```<app-image-viewer>``` because it renders before the areURL is ready.

Comment: Good point, Now image won't load at all, even after artURL is populated. Is there a way i can call it manually?

Comment: `showcase.component.ts:30 http://localhost/artworks/art/a/abbati/abbati1.jpg` Yes i am sure it's declared and being populated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because the artURL variable has nothing, it is not initialized when loading your component.

You need to establish at least one empty string, for example:

```
artURL ="";
```

Or have a default image shown in what the Data Service obtains the final URL, and the same angular framework will refresh the image when you assign the value of the final URL to artURL;

When you put a fixed url it shows no error because artURL is no longer an empty variable, it already has a value.

Comment: Funny, something so simple can be so annoying. Thank you, its resolved.